# adding new string in the middle of another one - c

Tags: c, string, append

my task is to write a string, then write a part of that string that needs to be replaced with one other string. I managed to make it work but if the replaced string is longer that part of string that is needed to replace, it just "eats" some of letters. Can I get little help with this task ?
Example of working code :

Input:

```
This is a beautiful day.
END
```

Input2:

```
a be
```

Input3:

```
not a bee
```

Expected Output:

```
This is not a beeautiful day.
```

My output:

```
This is not a beeful day.
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 1000

main(){
    char unos[MAX+1];
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    printf("Enter text. For end type END\n");
    while (1){
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", unos, &c);
        i = strstr(unos, "END") - unos;
        if (i >= 0){
            unos[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    char trazena_zamjena[MAX + 1] = "\0";
    char zamjena[MAX + 1];
    printf("Enter part that needs to be replaced : ");
    i = 0;
    do{
        scanf("%c", &trazena_zamjena[i]);
        if (trazena_zamjena[i] == '\n') {
            trazena_zamjena[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        i++;
    } while (trazena_zamjena[i] != '\n');
    printf("Enter replacing text : ");
    i = 0;
    do{
        scanf("%c", &zamjena[i]);
        if (zamjena[i] == '\n') {
            zamjena[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        i++;
    } while (zamjena[i] != '\n');
    int l = i;
    char *ptr;
    ptr = strstr(unos, trazena_zamjena);
    printf("pointer : %d %p", ptr, ptr);
    strncpy(ptr, zamjena, l);
    printf("%s\n", unos);
}
```

Comment: If you want to read a whole line, don't use `scanf` using a convoluted format string, use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", unos, &c);` seems wrong to me

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg input of code is working fine, the one with making a change is not working properly. We haven't get to fgets in class yet, so we can't use it.

Comment: @AntonioGvardijan so you are not allowed to use `fgets` (?!).

Comment: @Michael Walz no. LPs it's correct, this part works perfectly.

Comment: @AntonioGvardijan did you try debugging your code ?

Comment: @Michael Walz yes, there is not a single error, but there needs to be something else so I can add remaining parts of string after a pointer ptr, but I just can't figure out how. String that I put inside first string just overlaps letters that doesn't have to be replaced.

Comment: You are overwriting the string with `strncpy`, so the behaviour of your program is correct. If you want to _insert_ characters, well you must insert them by moving the end of the string further. Take a piece of paper and draw the contents of your `unos` buffer before and after the replacement.

Comment: This is what gcc says about your first scanf..... _warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]_

Answer (score 0):

Let's forget the endianness.
When you use a string in C, you put a sequence of character terminated by `'\0'` in the memory.

Suppose you have the following string `char * str = "string";` which have the address `str`.
By using

```
ptr = strstr(str, "i");
```

`ptr` value will be `str+3` (the address of the character `'i'`)
So imagine you try to replace `'i'` by `"ae"`.

```
strncpy(ptr, "ae", 2);
```

will write the `'a'` at the address pointed to by `ptr` (the `'i'`) and the `'e'` at the address pointed to by `ptr + 1` (here, it's the address of the `'n'`)
If the replaced substring is to small, you should shift all the followig characters.

You can modify the end of your code by

```
printf("pointer : %d %p", ptr, ptr);
int len_substr = strlen(trazena_zamjena);
if (l > len_substr)
  strncpy(ptr + l,  ptr + len_substr, strlen(ptr + len_substr));
strncpy(ptr, zamjena, l);
```

You have a similar problem if the string you add is smaller than the substring to remove.

Comment: That's a comment rather than an answer.